# How to connect to sqlserver 2008 R2 using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql-server

I need to connect to the database using JavaScript and I have used the following code

```
function Accept() {
             var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
             var connectionstring = "Data Source=mydatasource;Initial Catalog=DJ;User ID=sa;Password=mypass;Provider=SQLOLEDB;Persist Security Info=True";
             connection.Open(connectionstring);
             var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
             rs.Open("SELECT username FROM tbl_login where username='aby'", connection);
             rs.MoveFirst
             while (!rs.eof) {
                 document.write(rs.fields(1));
                 rs.movenext;
             }
             rs.close;
             connection.close; 
        }
```

But I am getting a error like this

Microsoft JScript runtime error: `[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.`

Comment: Using JavaScript to connect to your server is a bad idea from security point of view, You should use webservices and / or Ajax calls to mimic same functionality.

Comment: And connecting to SQL as sa from your app is also unwise.

Comment: I can't even begin to count the number of issues at hand accessing a database from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript code is accessing local resources on client PC.

So, it's searching for a database server on client PC.

You'd better use JQuery or [ASP.Net PageMethods](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=109&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) to make an Ajax request to the server which would handle database access logic.

Answer (score 0):

try to use a sql authentication to connect to your database
because i think your account is not working